# How do I extract translatable strings from a glade (Builder) file?

Tags: gtk, gettext, glade, mingw32, xgettext

In command prompt I wrote:

```
C:\Users\Waqar Ali Khan\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MedicalEmergency>xgettext -d
MedicalEmergency -o LocaleStrings.pot main.cpp MedicalEmergency.glade
xgettext: Language "glade" is not supported. xgettext relies on expat.
```

This version was built without expat.

I tried to locate the libexpat and it was there with the xgettext.exe but still I'm getting this error, can any one guide me how do I extract translatable strings from a glade file?

I know i m doing right but this error is weird no where mentioned in any tutorial :(

I'm on Windows using Netbeans IDE with GTK+ - 2.0 and MinGW with MSYS.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to use Intltool for extracting strings from Glade files. By coincidence, I am currently writing a [tutorial](http://ptomato.github.com/advanced-gtk-techniques) on that. Look in the ["Setting up *Gettext*" section](http://ptomato.name/advanced-gtk-techniques/html/gettext-project.html).

Note that to use Intltool, you will have to download and build that somehow. I really hope it works on Windows, but I honestly have no idea.

Comment: Sir i m very beginner and i saw ur link but i did not understand how to build it :(

Comment: @Waqar Ali Khan, What specific problems are you running into after you read his link? Is it still the same as in the original post?

Comment: The tutorial is now online, as a work-in-progress. (Hosted on the excellent Github Pages, a feature I only discovered the other day!) I've updated the link in my answer.